# How grep all lines that are exactly 12 words long?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I need someone smarter than me help me figure this out since I have been staring at the grep documentation for 2 hours witouth a solution.

I have several large text files containing random text, code, .... now I need to grep all lines that are exactly 12 words long. See the data example below:

```
Lookahead siz/thr: 100/33
  addr:1MrSDrsyHZRfjTjfpg4bpCdFsGzmb2GJps  hash160:e4bbf3aba7251fdb8a058ea504040302d6f66a69  (M, root)
  addr:1PzRBgxmGvZg5UgiS8gJB7b5pTaFX5vWsH  hash160:fc2eaa43be38a10008103038acd08572267795d7  (M/0H, account)
  addr:1DAgXyoaCeMuD7hb3YpAevNJJguwk8hrKA  hash160:857641262b10ed2f57c2d73a2beda02aebfbcde5  (M/0H/0, external)
sell fiction also forum flute expose circle ill enlist frown picnic trouble

Key to watch:      zpub6n2GV1BffVoWhcAL6nEWCCcoLo4Rzpz8r3zX1ThexHEFgpcN3MV1rnWeQPU1369UMWqanDYuLRAosLevUDXfhPF5ATZRtyf2KqMANcLDcdq
Lookahead siz/thr: 100/33
  addr:bc1q8lnwa7dskx649nk06qn9dnyfenrugca8qxj7ms  hash160:3fe6eef9b0b1b552cecfd02656cc89ccc7c463a7  (M, root)
  addr:bc1q8sgd3el8ssenq46n6u7dq8hak6ewrvpr63fng8  hash160:3c10d8e7e78433305753d73cd01efdb6b2e1b023  (M/1H, account)
  addr:bc1qmm34vkd3xm5s6tvh039vvyyj37v73e22y43c89  hash160:dee35659b136e90d2d977c4ac610928f99e8e54a  (M/1H/0, external)
  addr:bc1q9a7tqu44jzlt3duae2l734mjlp7xn5x6793csy  hash160:2f7cb072b590beb8b79dcabfe8d772f87c69d0da  (M/1H/1, internal)

Lookahead siz/thr: 100/33
  addr:1MrSDrsyHZRfjTjfpg4bpCdFsGzmb2GJps  hash160:e4bbf3aba7251fdb8a058ea504040302d6f66a69  (M, root)
  addr:1PzRBgxmGvZg5UgiS8gJB7b5pTaFX5vWsH  hash160:fc2eaa43be38a10008103038acd08572267795d7  (M/0H, account)
  addr:1DAgXyoaCeMuD7hb3YpAevNJJguwk8hrKA  hash160:857641262b10ed2f57c2d73a2beda02aebfbcde5  (M/0H/0, external)

hammer wing paddle brain photo panic memory artwork toward work potato company

Lookahead siz/thr: 100/33
  addr:1MrSDrsyHZRfjTjfpg4bpCdFsGzmb2GJps  hash160:e4bbf3aba7251fdb8a058ea504040302d6f66a69  (M, root)
  addr:1PzRBgxmGvZg5UgiS8gJB7b5pTaFX5vWsH  hash160:fc2eaa43be38a10008103038acd08572267795d7  (M/0H, account)
  addr:1DAgXyoaCeMuD7hb3YpAevNJJguwk8hrKA  hash160:857641262b10ed2f57c2d73a2beda02aebfbcde5  (M/0H/0, external)
```

From this data above it should find 2 lines that are 12 words long:

```
sell fiction also forum flute expose circle ill enlist frown picnic trouble
hammer wing paddle brain photo panic memory artwork toward work potato company
```

I hope I explained correctly, please excuse my ignorance. Thank you.

Comment: Possibly `awk 'NF == 12 {print}' inputfile`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unsure if it works but I did ask for grep. But thank you for responding kind sir.

Comment: Sometimes there are better tools than grep. You have a goal — in this case awk accomplishes your goal better than grep does. Don't prematurely lock yourself into one idea of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the separator between the words are spaces that would do the job using grep.

```
[lucas@lucasmachine ~]$ grep -E '^.* .* .* .* .* .* .* .* .* .* .* .*$' test 
sell fiction also forum flute expose circle ill enlist frown picnic trouble
hammer wing paddle brain photo panic memory artwork toward work potato company
```

```
[lucas@lucasmachine ~]$ cat test 
Lookahead siz/thr: 100/33
  addr:1MrSDrsyHZRfjTjfpg4bpCdFsGzmb2GJps  hash160:e4bbf3aba7251fdb8a058ea504040302d6f66a69  (M, root)
  addr:1PzRBgxmGvZg5UgiS8gJB7b5pTaFX5vWsH  hash160:fc2eaa43be38a10008103038acd08572267795d7  (M/0H, account)
  addr:1DAgXyoaCeMuD7hb3YpAevNJJguwk8hrKA  hash160:857641262b10ed2f57c2d73a2beda02aebfbcde5  (M/0H/0, external)
sell fiction also forum flute expose circle ill enlist frown picnic trouble

Key to watch:      zpub6n2GV1BffVoWhcAL6nEWCCcoLo4Rzpz8r3zX1ThexHEFgpcN3MV1rnWeQPU1369UMWqanDYuLRAosLevUDXfhPF5ATZRtyf2KqMANcLDcdq
Lookahead siz/thr: 100/33
  addr:bc1q8lnwa7dskx649nk06qn9dnyfenrugca8qxj7ms  hash160:3fe6eef9b0b1b552cecfd02656cc89ccc7c463a7  (M, root)
  addr:bc1q8sgd3el8ssenq46n6u7dq8hak6ewrvpr63fng8  hash160:3c10d8e7e78433305753d73cd01efdb6b2e1b023  (M/1H, account)
  addr:bc1qmm34vkd3xm5s6tvh039vvyyj37v73e22y43c89  hash160:dee35659b136e90d2d977c4ac610928f99e8e54a  (M/1H/0, external)
  addr:bc1q9a7tqu44jzlt3duae2l734mjlp7xn5x6793csy  hash160:2f7cb072b590beb8b79dcabfe8d772f87c69d0da  (M/1H/1, internal)

Lookahead siz/thr: 100/33
  addr:1MrSDrsyHZRfjTjfpg4bpCdFsGzmb2GJps  hash160:e4bbf3aba7251fdb8a058ea504040302d6f66a69  (M, root)
  addr:1PzRBgxmGvZg5UgiS8gJB7b5pTaFX5vWsH  hash160:fc2eaa43be38a10008103038acd08572267795d7  (M/0H, account)
  addr:1DAgXyoaCeMuD7hb3YpAevNJJguwk8hrKA  hash160:857641262b10ed2f57c2d73a2beda02aebfbcde5  (M/0H/0, external)

hammer wing paddle brain photo panic memory artwork toward work potato company

Lookahead siz/thr: 100/33
  addr:1MrSDrsyHZRfjTjfpg4bpCdFsGzmb2GJps  hash160:e4bbf3aba7251fdb8a058ea504040302d6f66a69  (M, root)
  addr:1PzRBgxmGvZg5UgiS8gJB7b5pTaFX5vWsH  hash160:fc2eaa43be38a10008103038acd08572267795d7  (M/0H, account)
  addr:1DAgXyoaCeMuD7hb3YpAevNJJguwk8hrKA  hash160:857641262b10ed2f57c2d73a2beda02aebfbcde5  (M/0H/0, external)
```

Answer (score 4):

Or a slightly more concise:

```
$ grep -E '(\w+( |$)){12}' test
sell fiction also forum flute expose circle ill enlist frown picnic trouble
hammer wing paddle brain photo panic memory artwork toward work potato company
```